# How to store data from editText in a txt file and store the file on the phone?

Tags: android, file, kotlin, storage

This is my code so far, supposedly this helps generate a file but I can't find it anywhere. I believe that's becuase there isn't a file path or directory provided. So what should I add to properly set the path?

```
 fun generateFile(){
    val fileName = "dataFile.txt"
    try {
        val fos = openFileOutput(fileName, MODE_PRIVATE)
        val data: String = binding.text.toString()
        fos.write(data.toByteArray())
        fos.flush()
        fos.close()
    } catch (e: IOException) {
        e.printStackTrace()
    }
    binding.text.setText("")
    Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"writing to file " + fileName.toString() + "completed...",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

}
```

Answer (score 2):

> I believe that's becuase there isn't a file path or directory provided

There is one implied by `openFileOutput()`. That puts the file into the directory referred to by `getFilesDir()` on `Context`.

> but I can't find it anywhere

That location is part of [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2019/10/06/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). That file is accessible by your app, but not by users. On `debug` builds of your app, you can get it via tools like Android Studio's Device File Explorer.

Comment: so what do I do? 

My goal is to create a text file and store it on my phone with the data from the edit text. This is a prototype for something I want to implement in another project but I doing it separately to properly understand how this works.

Comment: @MohamedElKayal: " My goal is to create a text file and store it on my phone with the data from the edit text" -- you are doing that right now. If you are looking for the content to be accessible directly by users, you are best served using `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument()` and let the user decide where that content should go (see [this free book chapter](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack/pages/chap-content-001.html) for more on that).

Comment: so basically I do in fact have a file now but he issue is its accessibility to users?

Comment: @MohamedElKayal: Correct.